# Overwriting Devise after_sign_in_path_for gives error: Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm overwriting `after_sign_in_path_for` in my `ApplicationController`.

Here's the method, using Domainatrix to parse the URL:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      "#{resource.subdomain}." + host(request.url) + ":3000/profile" 
  end

  def subdomain(url)
    Domainatrix.parse(url).subdomain
  end

  def host(url)
    Domainatrix.parse(url).host
  end
```

When I click "submit" once my logs are:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-26 17:10:03 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0aZ8da/kt+uxPDvzQj4ypyVDgTBW7FzRNR7uHN6Hryo=", "user"=>{"email"=>"EMAIL", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'EMAIL' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 16  [["last_sign_in_at", Thu, 27 Feb 2014 00:05:30 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Thu, 27 Feb 2014 00:10:03 UTC +00:00], ["sign_in_count", 65], ["updated_at", Thu, 27 Feb 2014 00:10:03 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to trevor.lvh.me:3000/profile
Completed 302 Found in 70ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

It shows it's redirecting to the correct URL, but nothing actually happened.

If I click "submit" a second time, nothing happens and the following log is produced (notice the **2nd to last line**):

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-26 17:10:08 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0aZ8da/kt+uxPDvzQj4ypyVDgTBW7FzRNR7uHN6Hryo=", "user"=>{"email"=>"EMAIL", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 16 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to trevor.lvh.me:3000/profile
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

To add further mystery, when I change `after_sign_in_path_for` to:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.subdomain == subdomain(request.url)
  "#{root_url}profile"
  end
end
```

It redirects to `trevor.lvh.me:3000/profile` correctly.

Any idea what this `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected` error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      "#{resource.subdomain}." + host(request.url) + ":3000/profile" 
  end
```

With

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      "http://#{resource.subdomain}." + host(request.url) + ":3000/profile" 
 end
```

`http://` Protocol is missing.

Comment: Question: if I make force_ssl = true, will this automatically redirect to the https equivalent?

Comment: Here we are hardcoding `http://`, but you could check the value of `force_ssl` and set the protocol accordingly.

Comment: Check the value of `Rails.application.config.force_ssl` in a if-else block and accordingly set the protocol. Hope i get an upvote. :)

Comment: I had similar issue but in my case I had url with sufix `_path` instead of `_url` in `after_sign_in_path_for` method.